# trouble with using variables as format precision

Tags: python, precision, valueerror

I have been trying to use a variable as a specifer in float precision to try to limit the number of decimal places shown for pi:

```
num = float(input("What decimal point do you want pi to be displayed to?(Up to 15) "))

print(format(math.pi, '.(num)f'))
```

when i run it, it shows the `ValueError: Format specifier missing precision`

I was wondering if there was any other way of writing it so i would be able to use a variable. Im pretty new and its probably a really simple mistake, but i dont know.

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: you could use `round()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string formatting operator with `.*` as the formatting option:

```
from math import pi
print('%.*f' % (5, pi))
```

This outputs:

```
3.14159
```

Comment: I like this trick even better than the "recommended" format string style :)

Answer (score 2):

you can just pass it in as a format argument ...

```
num="3"
print("{pi:0.{num}f}".format(pi=22/7.0,num=num))
```